# C# - .Contains - where string has quote marks in it

Tags: c#, .net

in C#, can I use `.Contains` to check if a string contains a value within quotation marks?
e.g., if the string I'm evaluating contains

```
He said "something"
```

I want to do something like:

```
strEval.Contains("He said "something"")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. You will need to escape the quotes, so they do not terminate the string:

```
strEval.Contains("He said \"something\"");
```

Have look at [MSDN on escape sequences in C# strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

Comment: Also just to add if it's a verbatim string you can double quote: `strEval.Contains(@"He said ""something""");`

Comment: Just to add, what id the string contains text after the last", eg (He said "something" again) thanks

Comment: @PedroBenylin, the string could also be "He said \"something\" test test".

Answer (score 5):

This problem is unrelated to `string.Contains`. The real question is how to write a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) containing `"` in C#. For this there are several possibilities:

1. Escape it with a `\`: `"He said \"something\""`
2. Use an verbatim string prefixed with `@` where you duplicate the `"`: `@"He said ""something"""`. This is mainly useful if the original string contains many backslashes, such as in a regex.
3. Use the hex value of `"`, but that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

You have to just escape the quotation mark :

```
strEval.Contains("He said \"something\"")
```